# Why can't I explicitly transmit a null value to the server?

Tags: protocol-buffers

Why is this so difficult?

```
syntax = "proto3";

message Foo {
    optional float field1 = 1;
    optional int32 field2 = 2;
}
```

On the server, I simply want to know if the client has specified a null or not. If the field is explicitly set to null, then I want the web service to act on it (by setting the corresponding field to null in the database). If the client hasn't explicitly specified a null, then I don't want to take any action. The client doesn't always have the entire universe of fields that the database has, so often it will only change the fields that the user is interested in changing, without wanting to update the entire record. This often includes explicitly setting things to null.

The above code works for setting the default value, in that I can query HasField1 on the server to see that it was set on the client side, but I can't explicitly set field1 to null on the client (because the base type is an int/float).

```
syntax = "proto3";

message Foo {
    optional google.protobuf.FloatValue field1 = 1;
    optional google.protobuf.Int32Value field2 = 2;
}
```

This option allows me to set the field value to null, but it removes all the generated code that works to indicate the field has been set!

Why can't I just have an int? with the 'optional' code. Why can't I explicitly tell the server that a field has been set to null and ignore the ones I haven't set on the client side?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `oneof` as follows:

```
syntax = "proto3";

message Foo {
    oneof field1 {
        bool field1IsNull = 1;
        float field1Val = 2;
    }
    oneof field2 {
        bool field2IsNull = 3;
        int32 field2Val = 4;
    }
}
```

Read up on `oneof` here: https://protobuf.dev/programming-guides/proto3/#oneof

Comment: You cannot do that since you were not a part of Google circle of engineers who came up with gRPC protocol. There are more flexible protocols that allow what you want. For example this one is for WebSocket connection: https://www.npmjs.com/package/rbmp

Comment: Yes, I've seen that answer. I've got 500 fields I need to manage for orders. That solution more than doubles the work I need to do to support one of my tables. It's truly ugly and unsupportable in real-life situations. In addition, it completely screws up my plans to automap the fields on the server side.

Comment: if you are dealing with 500+ fields, you probably need to make your contract as a property bag or use bson.

Comment: And, again, this architecture completely screws up any plans to use to auto map the 95% of the fields that have the same or similar names and the other 5% than need some manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, the [protobuf wire format](https://protobuf.dev/programming-guides/encoding/) doesn't support that.

Protobuf encodes *state* rather than *change*. So it's easy to encode a message which doesn't set a field, but there's no way of representing the notion of "clear this field".

One option for your use case would be to use a *field mask* separately in your request, to basically say "Please update the database with fields `x` and `y` to match the ones in this message, including clearing those fields in the database if they're not set in the message."

Protobuf includes a [well-known type for field masks](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/src/google/protobuf/field_mask.proto), and there is code in most languages to help use it. However, please be aware that this is very much a "here be dragons" area... the way that field mask semantics are described in `field_mask.proto` differs from the semantics described in [AIP-161](https://google.aip.dev/161) for example. (I hope to try to unify things to at least some extent over time, but this is a really fiddly area, and I don't want to break anyone.) You *may* want to come up with your own similar scheme to meet your requirements rather than rely on anything to do with the well-known type.

Would life be simpler if the protobuf wire format had a representation for "clear this field"? For this particular scenario, yes. I suspect it would introduce a *lot* of other issues though.